# Image game php send image on a timer

Tags: php, image, timer

I need to make a game where the user has to guess who is in a blurred photo.From 5 to 5 second the picture gets clearer but the user gets less points the more time passes.How can I send a blurred picture to the user on a timer ?I cand't make the reuest to the server with js because the user can modify the js script to....for example ask the server for the clearest image even though the time is not right.Js is not reliable for this because it can be modified from the server.So again the question,how can I send to the user on a timer an image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requesting it dynamically with JS is your best option. You can attach tokens to every image level and only accept a request token if the previous one has already been used. For example, if you have five images with different clarity stages you can number them from 1-5 and only accept a request for 5 if 4, 3, 2, and 1 have already been requested. You can make it harder for the user to not cheat by checking how many seconds have passed between requests. Make sure to take latency into account though.

Comment: Using java or any other (like dotnet) may be option. First user has to install your application then play the game. Or through XUL (firefox extension) and similar extension on chrome and IE also.

Comment: But client's internet speed, server traffic etc will also have effect if you use plain js, How can you handle it?

Comment: Using java or silverlight are also valid options, but they are not as accessible as plain JS or not cross-platform. Handling latency is only a problem when the client has a very slow connection when requesting the image X and a fast connection when requesting image X+1. In most cases you'll have a ~200ms deviation which isn't that bad. Also if you reset the JS timer to request the next image only when the current one has been received latency shouldn't be a problem since it should be greater than the amount of time between frames.

Answer (score 1):

- Record (session, db, etc) when the user starts the game/level
- Use GD/ImageMagick to blur the image and PHP to serve it
- Use JS to refresh the image `src` every x seconds/minutes

This way, you're not dependent on anything other than the server-side logic. The user can even refresh the page to obtain the less-blurred image should they not have JS.

Comment: Use JS to refresh the image src every x seconds/minutes?? tell me code, i will edit it. In place of x i will write x-4 using firebug or any other way, i can even use curl.

Comment: @web2students.com I'm not quite sure you understand. You can refresh it as many times as you like, the blurring is controlled solely by the server and is not influenced by the number of times it is requested - which is where the benefits of my solution lies.